# Moving UIView from One Tab to another

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uibutton

I'm making this type of screen.
[image: Tabs] 
 I've used 3 `UIButton` and programmatically gave them border. The little red line is a `UIView`. I've provided a constraint to `UIView` **Equal Widths** as **Trending Button**.
Now my question that when user taps the next button this `UIView` should move to the next one.
 View Controller is `600x600` and next button is at `200x0` so if I change the value of `UIView` to 200 that will be hard coded and it'll alter according to the screen size. I want it to be perfect and don't know any other way.
**UPDATE:**
I'm using `AutoLayout` so for this purpose I used `[self.buttonBottomView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:YES];` and when I run the app the buttons were messed up like in the screenshot. I've applied some `constraints` on buttons.
[image]

Comment: you can try hiding and showing the red line bottom of the button. this will be easy

Comment: Works just perfect but without animation. Thanks :D

Comment: you can add animation also by try uiview transition

Comment: [UIView transitionWithView:self.view duration:1.5
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromBottom //change to whatever animation you like
                animations:^ {
                    [self.view addSubview:myImageView1];
                    [self.view addSubview:myImageView2];
                }
                completion:^(BOOL finished){
                    if (finished) {
                        // Successful
                    }
                    NSLog(@"Animations completed.");
                    // do something...
                }];

Answer (score 2):

You can use `NSLayoutConstraint` ,change it's `LeadingConstaint` when you tap on the next button.

**Code:**

```
- (void)changeSelectedByTapView:(UIView *)tapView {
    _currentSelectedView = tapView;
    self.lineImageViewLeadingConstaint.constant = tapView.frameX;
    self.lineImageViewWidthConstaint.constant = tapView.width;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f animations:^{
        [self.lineImageView.superview layoutIfNeeded];
    }];
}
```

Comment: your constraints must be wrong ,red line(view) level should be same as your button.

Answer (score 0):

change frame of your UIView.

```
view.frame = CGRectMake(0+buttonWidth*i, y, width, height);
```

i is index which is 0 for **Trending**, 1 for **Made by the fans** and 2 for **your rules**.

Also when you change frame for your view, it is shown only on one button at a time.